# Trigger javascript in href attribute with jQuery .click() (or similar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Unfortunately, I'm working with some 3rd party javascript, which inserts links into my pages. Rather than just use these links as is, I want to use proxy elements, which, when clicked, trigger the click event on the 3rd party links.

The 3rd party links pack javascript into the href attribute, like this:

```
<a id="horribleLink" href="javascript:doSomething()">Click me</a>
```

My proxy element looks like this:

```
<button rel="horribleLink" class="linkProxy">No, click me</button>
```

And a bit of jQuery'd javascript to link them together:

```
$('button.linkProxy').click(function(){
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).click();
});
```

Now, this works perfectly if the 3rd party link is <strike>just a standard link (`<a id="horribleLink" href="http://www.google.com">Click</a>`), or</strike> a slightly less horrible onclick (`<a href="#" id="horribleLink" onclick="doSomething()">Click</a>`), but when the javascript is inside the href attribute, triggering 'click' does nothing at all.

Can anyone tell me why, and if there's a reasonable workaround?

**Updated** As Millimetric said, the root cause looks to be that browsers prevent 'faking clicks' on anchors - I've removed my 'standard link' example, as that's another situation that doesn't work. The onclick handler does work, though, as you'd expect.

Comment: For the beginning, can you check the syntax? `onclick="doSomething()` should be `onclick="doSomething()"`

Comment: Shouldn't `href="javascript:doSomething"` be `href="javascript:doSomething()"`?

Comment: Fixed - they were just typos in my examples, not the real code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The accepted answer here goes into a little depth as to "why this is happening": [Can I call jquery click() to follow an <a> link if I haven't bound an event handler to it with bind or click already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-handl). Basically, it seems you can't do a click() on a link because the browser doesn't support fake clicking.

**One Work-around**:

If you set location.href for those cases, it works:

```
$('button.linkProxy').click(function(){
    location.href = $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).attr('href');
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uv29x/3/

**Two Work-around**:

You could just get the href of those links and do an `eval()` on them, right?

Comment: I realize this is awful in terms of security, but the setup kinda forces you to do it I think.

Comment: That's the workaround I've got at the moment - it works fine, but I'd really like to understand what's going on, too.

Comment: The accepted answer here goes into a little depth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-handl.  Basically, it seems you can't do a `click()` on a link because the browser doesn't support fake clicking.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, mainly for the comment above. I think I'll still use eval instead of location.href, but both workarounds are equally good(bad/ugly)! Thanks for your help!

Comment: np, I'll edit that comment into the body as it does address your initial question better.

Comment: That being said, I have this feeling that `eval` is worse than `location.href = `.  I don't know why as this is a bit above my pay grade.  Jon Skeet? John Resig?

Comment: Third work around: http://jsfiddle.net/FKaYR/ (injecting `<form>` into the document, setting its action) though it's very much like changing the `location.href` thus only giving it as comment.

Comment: As far as I can tell, eval() is no worse from a security point of view than a javascript: href attribute. Anyone who can pass in something nasty to eval could just as easily re-write the href attribute and have their code executed that way. Both methods have the same privileges, I think.

Comment: +1 Beejamin. Just go the debugger and inject whatever you want. Yes it is hideous to use within more or less any other language, but in js it's fair game, if a little slow.

Comment: Weird, fiddle used to work :)  You should make a new one with the sample code and edit the answer.  That's what wikis are for!

Answer (score 4):

Set `window.location` to the `href` value.

```
$('button.linkProxy').click(function(){
    window.location = $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).attr('href');
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dmSUm/

Comment: Interesting approach! I can see why this works, but it feels even ickier to me than the eval method.

Comment: @Beejamin: Don't know which method is better, I just prefer to avoid `eval`.

Comment: *slight* emendation to accommodate all three types of links: http://jsfiddle.net/dmSUm/2/

Answer (score 2):

I'd just finished typing this up when I saw Milimetric's answer . Here's the code anyway for what it's worth -

```
eval($('#horribleLink').attr('href').replace('javascript:',''));
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I'd resorted to before I asked the question (I should probably have mentioned). I'm hoping someone knows the *why*, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the native Javascript `click` method and you've got yourself a working click!

```
$('button.linkProxy').click(function(){
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).click()[0].click();
});
```

I kept the jQuery `click` *assuming* that Javascript `click` will bypass jQuery `trigger`s in which case you'll want to keep both. Otherwise, if I'm wrong (or you don't need to account for `trigger`) you can reduce it to:

```
$('button.linkProxy').click(function(){
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel'))[0].click();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly the question, the issue is that you have something like this:

```
 <a href="javascript:alert('hello');" onclick="javascript:alert('clicked');">Test</a>
```

And you claim that when the javascript is on the href, the onclick event is not fired. Correct? If so, what I am seeing is that both get fired, first onclick and then the javascript inside href.

Comment: This is not the problem at all.  The problem is he's trying to trigger the `href` action from another JavaScript function.

Comment: No - the links I'm working with have no onclick, only javascript inside the href. It doesn't fire when the click event is triggered programmatically.

Comment: @Beejamin I see what you mean.