# how to make a keyboard navigation using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <meta name="author" content="bbbbb" />

        <title>Untitled 2</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script> 

    <style>
    #test ul{list-style:none;}
    #test li{width:75px;height:25px;padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;}
    .active{background:#AEABAB;}
    a.active{color:#ffffff;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
      $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 38: // up arrow
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
    break; 
    }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="test">
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a  href="test.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">My work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i don't want to use `"window.location.href = 'index.html';"` but want to click my navigation link using click method is it possible???

---

**[you can check here](http://www.instatutorial.com/jquery-keyboard-navigation)**

i have created a page for keyboard navigation!

Comment: Most likely the browser will block using `.click()` to navigate to a link. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927215/trigger-javascript-in-href-attribute-with-jquery-click-or-similar

Comment: [jKey](http://oscargodson.com/labs/jkey/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#ID').click();` doesn't target the href in  but if you've defined onclick it target's that.

so

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {        
    switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 38: // up arrow
        $('#work').click();
        break; 
    }
    });    
});
```

will execute `<a href="#" id="work" onclick="alert('test')">Test</a>` the alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/2SKAH/6/

Comment: If you want to link it somewhere you can add onclick="location.href='url.html';" to it http://jsfiddle.net/2SKAH/7/

Comment: Check it's solution here....http://www.instatutorial.com/jquery-keyboard-navigation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to click the 'active' link then you can replace window.location.href = 'index.html' with:

```
window.location.href = $("li.active a").attr('href');
```

If you simply want to map key 38 to that link then you should give the anchor an id (indexAnchor) so

```
<a id="indexAnchor" href="text.html">Home</a>
```

and

```
window.location.href = $("#indexAnchor").attr('href');
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2SKAH/5/) is an example.

Comment: you took me wrong sir thats not what i mean... i m able to find my active link but as i am pressing my keyboard key.... it is not responding me... at console.log() it gives me perfect link which i want to click.... i dn't know what is the reason....

Comment: I am not entirely sure why, but calling click does not work.  I have run into this issue before and my solution was grabbing the href attribute and setting the window's location with that value.

Comment: `<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
      $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 38: // up arrow
    $("p").click();
    break; 
    }
    });
    $("p").click(function(){
        
        $("p").css({'background':'black'});
        
        
    });
});
</script>`

Comment: this above script is running and making background black but links are not working....

Comment: Is it necessary that the link is clicked and navigates to the anchor's href?  If you just need to fire a click event look at Ilkka Syrjäkari's answer.

Comment: i found a way around and created a post on it if you want to check you can check here...http://www.instatutorial.com/jquery-keyboard-navigation

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html a:first').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, give each link an ID or class and use:

```
case 38: //Up arrow
$('#home').click();
```

That will cause the link with an id of *home* to be clicked.