# Button ok but href link doesn't fire

Tags: jquery

I have JQuery code:

```
$("#step1Skip").on("click", function(event){
    $('#chooseTheme, #addImages, #addVideo, #finalStep').hide();
    $('#addLogo').show();
});
```

If I use a button e.g.

```
<button type="button" id="step1Skip">Skip this step >></button>
```

This works fine. BUT, if I try the same with a simple link:

```
<a href="#" id="step1Skip">Skip this step</a>
```

It does nothing, simply doesn't work. Why is that?

I don't try them at the same time, so it's not an ID issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your browser is trying to follow the link. Try using [**.preventDefault()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$("#step1Skip").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#chooseTheme, #addImages, #addVideo, #finalStep').hide();
    $('#addLogo').show();
});
```

This will prevent the default action of the link from occurring.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a link, the link is performing it's default action. You need to prevent it from doing so, and use `preventDefault()`

```
$("#step1Skip").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#chooseTheme, #addImages, #addVideo, #finalStep').hide();
    $('#addLogo').show();
});
```

Another note - this is useful for only the `<a>`.  Since buttons do not have a default action, they are unhindered by using `event.preventDefault()`

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186165/how-to-trigger-the-default-action-event-of-a-html-link-anchor-element) can be helpful on understanding how default actions work with a link.