# GET request by clicking on link by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dynamically I've created a link with download attribute:

```
var link = $('<a>', {
  href:file_url, 
  download:file_name
}).appendTo('body');
```

By clicking on that link programmably I want to download a file with given file name.

Is it possible to trigger GET request by clicking on that link by jQuery?

I know about `jquery.fileDownload.js` plugin, but I need to set a file name on client side not on server side.

Comment: Precisely what do you mean by 'trigger GET' request? Do you mean an ajax request?

Comment: Have a look at [How to trigger the default action/event of a HTML link (anchor element)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7186165/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, but opening the window will generate file with default name 'download' or something

Comment: @JeevanJose, just clicking on element is not making GET request to server

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Invoking click-event of an anchor tag from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980709/javascript-invoking-click-event-of-an-anchor-tag-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. You have a link and you want to generate a GET request on click. If this is correct then,

- To generate the click, you can simply use

> $('a').trigger('click');

- About the GET, clicking a link by default generates a GET request to the server.