# How to click the anchor using JQuery so that the href is also called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have an anchor and a text box as below:

```
 <div id="container">
        <input type="text" id="textBox" />       
        <a id="anchorTest" href="javascript: alert('inside anchorTest')">Click me</a>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to make the default button to the anchor when the enter key is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#anchorTest').click(function () {
                alert('clicked');
            });

            $('#container').keyup(function (e) {

                if (e.keyCode == 13) {                    
                    $('#anchorTest').triggerHandler('click');
                }
            });
        });
```

But the anchor href javascript is never called?

How to click the anchor using JQuery so that the href is also called?

I used the below code and it worked but is there any better way as it submits the form whereas I'd like to have a pure javascript code:

```
window.location = $('#anchorTest').attr('href');
```

Thanks

Comment: You should not put js in href. Do it with onClick instead. And I don't get what you are asking. You want the same thing to happen when you press enter in the textbox as when you click the link?

Comment: For anyone interested: http://jsfiddle.net/KhYtF/

Comment: @Halil; thanks, that explains the problem.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery handles the `click` event on anchor tags in a 'special' way. See this question for further information - [Can I call jquery click() to follow an <a> link if I haven't bound an event handler to it with bind or click already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand)

From the question above -

> I did some research and it seems that the .click is not suppose to
>   work with 'a' tags because the browser does not suport "fake clicking"
>   with javascript. I mean, you can't "click" an element with javascript.
>   With 'a' tags you can trigger its onClick event but the link won't
>   change colors (to the visited link color, the default is purple in
>   most browsers). So it wouldn't make sense to make the $().click event
>   work with 'a' tags since the act of going to the href attribute is not
>   a part of the onClick event, but hardcoded in the browser.

Comment: it's not just JQuery, with DOM that would behave in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Change your "triggerHandler" to just "trigger" and see if that resolves your issue.

I think triggerHandler bypasses the standard behavior and executes the "onclick" event handler in your case which is not set.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {                    
      $('#anchorTest').click();
}
```

Check from here http://jsfiddle.net/amBXV/

Comment: No, it didn't say "inside anchorTest" when I hit Enter inside the text input. [Chrome 14]

Comment: yeah, that just explains the problem not the solution.