# How to click on an image with a hyperlink using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, click, action, simulate

The HTML of the page I wish to use for this is as follows:

```
<A HREF= "http://www.example.com"
        TARGET="_new" status="Home Directory" title="Home Directory" 
        urn="Home Directory" FOLDER="http://www.example.com"><IMG align=textTop border="0" src="images/buttons/mywork.gif" alt="Select this icon to show your Home Folder" ></td>
```

How can I simulate a click on this hyperlinked image just using Javascript? I don't have edit privileges for this page so I need to work with what I have already got in the page (above)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I call jquery click() to follow an <a> link if I haven't bound an event handler to it with bind or click already?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand) - This question explains that clicking on links cannot be simulated using any `click` event. You have two options: `window.open('http://example.com')` or an artifical form using input `targe=_new`.

Comment: can I do the window.open option with the link found on the webpage in there (e.g. window.open('http://www.randomlinkeachtimefromwebpage.com')

Comment: Simplified code `<a href='http://example.com/' onclick='openNew(this);'><img/></a>`. JavaScript: `function openNew(a){window.open(a.href);}`. This code will probably not work in modern browsers due pop-up blockers, though.

Comment: Like I said though, I don't have the ability to edit the webpage, so is there any way to work with the code I already have?

Comment: If you're not able to edit the page, how are you going to inject JavaScript? That aside, what browsers do you have to support, and what are the unique characteristics of the link?

Comment: I'm using [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"**JAVASCRIPT HERE**"]; which is Objective-C. I just need the Javascript to inject into the page. Apart from that, I have no edit access...

Comment: Yes. Can you edit the question to be more clear? What are the specific characteristics of the anchor? How do we know how to match that anchor, based on its, say, attributes?

Comment: To direct the user to the anchor's target, we have to grab the `href` attribute of the anchor first. To do so, we need a DOM reference to the anchor. So, how do we get this reference? Examples: Is the link the first link in a page? Does the (parent of the) anchor have an ID-attribute? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebug plugin for firefox and code your javascript from the console. Google chrome also has a console.

Answer (score 0):

Give it an id for a start and then invoke using "apply"

```
var x = document.getElementById("linky");
x.onclick.apply(x);
```

Comment: Did you read my question properly? I put **I don't have edit privileges for this page so I need to work with what I have already got in the page** - please provide some code which works with the existing code without have to add anything (such as an ID tag)

Comment: Also, it's the only A HREF link on the page, so maybe I could find all A HREF links on the page and click on the first one using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [the jQuerify plug-in](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet). Then type `$('a').click();` in the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) console.

Comment: this is on an iPhone though (Safari for iOS) so I'm not sure that I can do that...