# link press using keys in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML page with jquery loaded in and 2 links on the page.

```
<a href='www.example.com'>Buttona</a>
<a href='www.example2.com'>Buttonb</a>
```

How can I make pressing the "1" key be like pressing the first link, and pressing the "2" key be like pressing the second link using jquery?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the links an id so you can reference them so

```
<a href='www.example.com' id="linkA">Buttona</a>
```

Then on your page add the jquery to capture the key up of 1 to find `linka` and click.

```
$("html").live("keyup", function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode === 49){
      //$("#linkA").click();
      window.location.href = $('#linkA').attr('href');
   }
}
```

If using jquery 1.7 you can use .on() instead on .live()

Comment: It is recognizing the key code but is not going to the link.  I am using 1.7.1...

Comment: `click()` just triggers the event. It doesn´t click the element and follow the link. Use `window.location.href = $('#linkA').attr('href');`

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't "accesskey" attribute be simpler ?

```
<a href='www.example.com' accesskey='0'>Buttona</a>
<a href='www.example2.com' accesskey='1'>Buttonb</a>
```

**EDIT** You may need to combine with *Alt* key

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method

```
$(window).bind('keyup',function(e) {
 if ( e.keyCode == 49 ) {
   // 1 
 }
 if ( e.keyCode == 50 ) {
   // 2 
 }
});
```