# Make a call to a custom protocol in Javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I'm running a script in a UIWebView which sends data back to the host application (in Objective-C). If I put a link on the page pointing to `myprotocol://some_data`, I receive the information on the host side.

How can I achieve the same behaviour in pure Javascript, without user interaction? Something like a AJAX call, but not over HTTP?

I'm using AngularJS, but any solution in Javascript is welcome.

Comment: See answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167100/how-to-make-a-jquery-get-ajax-request-to-a-private-custom-url-protocol

Comment: I saw that but "you have to start from the ground up" isn't pointing me towards some solution

Comment: You can't do ajax requests, but have you tried simply doing `window.location = 'myprotocol://';` ?

Comment: When I add a `window.location='myprotocol://';` the code execution simply stops there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that there was no way to do this without "cheating" in some way. I decided to create a `<a>` element in my page and dynamically change its `href` attribute, then triggering the `click` event on it with Javascript. Here is what I did :

**CSS**

```
a#sendToiOS {
  display:block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
  var sendToiOS = function(protocol, action, params) {
    var e = document.createElement('a');
    e.id = 'sendToiOS';
    var strParams = "";
    if(typeof params !== 'undefined') {
      Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key) {
        strParams += strParams != "" ? '&' : '';
        strParams += key+'='+encodeURI(params[key]);
      });
    }
    e.href = strParams.length > 0 ? protocol+'://'+action+'?'+strParams : protocol+'://'+action;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(e);
    e.click();
    e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
  }
```

Calling `sendToiOS('mycustomprotocol', 'some_action', {foo: 'bar', foo2: 1337});` would then trigger a call to `mycustomprotocol://some_action?foo=bar&foo2=1337`.

Comment: Huh - I didn't suggest manually triggering click() as I assumed this wouldn't work - nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I dug around inside the guts of [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) and it seems like they use an iframe bridge for this. Essentially they dynamically create an iframe (so the iframe domain is the same as the calling page), then update the iframe `src` to a custom protocol URL.

Interestingly the iframe bridge is a fallback mode for iOS4; they do use an XMLHttpRequest, but I'm not yet certain how they work around the same-domain policy.

EDIT: To do this they register a custom [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and then issue a `HEAD` request along with the desired data.

If you want to take a closer look, search for the `exec.js` file inside the `cordova-js.zip` file which comes with Cordova. You can find the custom protocol as `CDVURLProtocol.m` inside `cordova-ios.zip`.

Comment: Thank you. I finally decided to use a simpler workaround, but looking at the source code there is what pointed me in the right direction. I went with an easier implementation but still helped me! Thanks