# How to make JS wait until protocol execution finished

Tags: javascript, custom-url-protocol

I have a custom URL protocol handler `cgit:[...]`

It launches up a background process which configures some stuff on the local machine. The protocol works fine, i'm launching it from JavaScript (currently using `document.location = 'cgit:[...]'`), but i actually want JavaScript to wait until the associated program exits.

---

So basically the steps i want JavaScript to do:

1. JavaScript does something
2. JavaScript launches `cgit:[...]`
3. Javascript waits until `cgit:[...]` exits
4. JavaScript does something else

---

Code:

```
function launchCgit(params)
{
    showProgressBar();
    document.location="cgit:"+params;
    document.addEventListener( /* CGit-Program exited event */, hideProgressBar );
}
```

or:

```
function launchCgit(params)
{
    showProgressBar();
    // setLocationAndWait("cgit:"+params);
    hideProgressBar();
}
```

---

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: Adding some code would probably help answer the question.

Comment: ok, i'll edit some in

Comment: What is cgit:[...] going to launch?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, once you've set document.location you will redirect away from the page, stopping any JS from running. Maybe you want to make an AJAX call?

Comment: It launches a custom program written in c++ which acts like any other program. If you launch it from a command line for example, it would pause the execution there as well.

Comment: @c0d3rman Not quite, as it's a custom url protocol the browser (at least Opera - haven't tested it in other browsers yet) doesn't treat it as a new page to load, so Javascript execution after the call works fine. I just need Javascript to wait until the program exits, instead of directly executing the next line.

Comment: @Leso_KN since this isn't really an expected use of window.location I would doubt that there's an easy way. My recommendation would be to use an AJAX request (which is really easy with jQuery) and have the c++ program send a response when it's done. That way, whatever code needs to run after the c++ program can be run in the `done` function (or equivalent).

Comment: @c0d3rman Ah, that's a good idea. How would i make my program send a response to AJAX? Is it possible threw a simple `printf([...])`?

Comment: Excuse me, forgot to look it up first. Going to try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167100/how-to-make-a-jquery-get-ajax-request-to-a-private-custom-url-protocol) before asking on :)

Comment: ok, nevermind; i guess i'll just do some ugly workarround with `XmlHttpRequest`, `wget` and `window.setInterval` Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Great! I'm going to post my comment as an answer, but if you found something else that worked consider posting it as an answer so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i didn't find a suitable way to solve my problem using ajax requests or anything similar, i finally solved my problem using a kind-of-ugly workarround including `XmlHttpRequest`

---

For launching the protocol i'm still using `document.location=cgit:[...]`

I'm using a server side system including "lock-files" - that's like generic dummy files, with generated names for each request.

Once the user requests to open the custom protocol, such a file is being generated on the server specifically for that one protocol-opening-request.

I created a folder called "$locks" on the server where these files are being placed in. Once the protocol-associated program exits, the appropriate file is being deleted.

The website continuously checks if the file for a request still exists using `XmlHttpRequest` and fires a callback if it doesn't (example timout between tests: 1 sec).

The structure of the new files is the following:

- `lockThisRequest.php`: It creates a file in the $locks directory based on the `req` url-parameter.
- `unlockThisRequest.php`: It deletes a file in the $locks directory; again based on the `req` url-parameter.

The JavaScript part of it goes:

```
function launchCgit(params,callback)
{
    var lock = /* Generate valid filename from params variable */;

    // "Lock" that Request (means: telling the server that a request with this ID is now in use)
    var locker = new XmlHttpRequest();
    locker.open('GET', 'lockThisRequest.php?req='+lock, true)
    locker.send(null);

    function retry()
    {
        // Test if the lock-file still exists on the server
        var req = new XmlHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', '$locks/'+lock, true);
        req.onReadyStateChanged=function()
        {
            if (req.readyState == 4)
            {
                if (req.status == 200)
                {
                    // lock-file exists -> cgit has not exited yet
                    window.setTimeout(retry,1000);
                }
                else if (req.status == 404)
                {
                    // lock-file not found -> request has been proceeded
                    callback();
                }
            }
        }
        req.send(null);
    }
    document.location = 'cgit:'+params; // execute custom protocol
    retry(); // initialize lockfileCheck-loop
}
```

Ussage is:

```
launchCgit("doThisAndThat",function()
                           {
                               alert("ThisAndThat finished.");
                           });
```

the `lockThisRequest.php`-file:

```
<?php
    file_put_contents("$locks/".$_GET["req"],""); // Create lock file
?>
```

and `unlockThisRequest.php`:

```
<?php
    unlink("../\$locks/".$_GET["req"]); // Delete lock file
?>
```

---

The local program / script executed by the protocol can simply call something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl "http://servername/unlockThisRequest.php?req=$1"
```

after it finished.

---

As i just said this *works*, but it's anything else than nice (congratulations if you kept track of those instructions)

I'd rather prefered a more simple way and **(important)** this also may cause security issues with the `lockThisRequest.php` and `unlockThisRequest.php` files!

I'm fine with this solution, because i'm only using it on a password protected private page. But if you plan to use it on a public or non protected page, you may want to add some security to the php files.

---

Anyways, the solution works for me now, but if anyone finds a better way to do it - for example by using ajax requests - he/she would be very welcome to add that way to the respective stackoverflow-documentation or the like and post a link to it on this thread. I'd still be interested in alternative solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this isn't really an expected use of window.location I would doubt that there's an easy way. My recommendation would be to use an AJAX request and have the c++ program send a response when it's done. That way, whatever code needs to run after the c++ program can be run when the request completes.