# how to load page with jquery using the id name as url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

how can i tell jquery to use the `<a id="">` or `<a href="">` as a URL to load on click? For example URL page1.php. either by getting the href, or by getting the id and then appending .php

html

```
<a id="page1" class="load" href="page1.php">1</a>
<a id="page2" class="load" href="page2.php">2</a>
<a id="page3" class="load" href="page3.php">3</a>
```

jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $(".load").click(loadDynamic);  
    });  
    function loadDynamic() {  
        $("#load_in")  
            .load("",function (content) {  
                $(this).hide().fadeIn("slow");  
                return false;  
        }); 
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: [This][1] answers your question perfectly. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.href` to get the `href`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".load").click(loadDynamic);
});

function loadDynamic() {
    $("#load_in").load(this.href, function(content) {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn("slow");
    });
        return false;
}​
```

Of course you can use `this.id + ".php"` as well.

**Note** that you wrote `return false` inside the `load` callback thus it won't prevent the default anchor click! You should move it to the outer scope like in the answer.

---

For those of you complaining about `.click(fn)` against `on('click', fn)`

**Those are the same function**, `.click(fn)` is an alias for `on('click', fn)`:

> In the first two variations, this method is a shortcut for .bind("click", handler), as well as for .on("click", handler) as of jQuery 1.7.

[**jQuery docs**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: @Lix. They are the same. `click` is an alias to it. Read the docs: `In the first two variations, this method is a shortcut for .bind("click", handler), as well as for .on("click", handler) as of jQuery 1.7.`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this.href`:

```
$(".load").click(function() {
    $("#load_in").load(this.href, function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn("slow");
    });
    return false;
});
```

To get ID use simple `this.id`.

Comment: @gdoron Yours doesn't prevent default link action :P

Comment: @gdoron Count your brackets :D LOL

Comment: @Derek where is my +1 also? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.load("",function (content) {
```

With

```
.load(this.href, function (content) {
```