# Fire Click event in A-tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, anchor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I call jquery click() to follow an <a> link if I haven’t bound an event handler to it with bind or click already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand)

I wrote the following code.

```
<div style="background-color:orange">Click me to open the link
    <br>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://example.com">Link</a>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery('div').click(function(){
        jQuery('a').click();
    });

    jQuery('a').click(function(e){
       alert('It came here!');           
       e.stopPropagation();
       return true;   
    });
</script>
```

But the link is not opening.

UPDATE: added target attribute to A-tag.

Comment: See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/zZqQs/

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZeSdV/5/ its working fine..

Comment: @habeebperwad your fiddle works in chrome

Comment: @karaxuna I tried the OP's fiddle in Chrome, it doesn't work. Clicking on the DIV displays the alert, but doesn't link to example.com. Clicking on the A displays the alert and links to example.com. I think the intent is that clicking on the DIV should be exactly like clicking on the A.

Comment: The jQuery `click()` function only runs handlers on anchors that have been bound to the element, it doesn't invoke the browser's default action. There are lots of past questions about this, see the Related list in the sidebar.

Comment: Instead of showing the interest to close the question, you could help me to solve the issue. I checked several questions. But I couldn't find any solution. So I asked here. It seems that stackoverflow is an encyclopedia not QA-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using a selector that will match **all** `<a>` tags on your page. Perhaps you want to give your `<a>` an id attribute so that you can target one specific element...

```
<a href="foobar.html" id="foo">foo</a>
```

You could also try use the `trigger` function to simulate a click on the element -

```
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

One last thing to mention is that you didn't actually call the method to open the link. You can try use this code -

```
jQuery('a').click(function(e){
   alert('It came here!');
   window.open($(this).attr('href'));    
   return false;   
});
```

---

Reference -

- [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> **Description:** Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the
>   matched elements for the given event type.

Comment: Lix, To make the question simpler, I used the tag itself as selector.

Comment: @hab - Ok... It just looked a little strange :)

Comment: The jQuery documentation says that `.click()` is equivalent to `.trigger("click")`.

Comment: @bam - you are correct. But when things stop working, it never hurts to try different variants.

Comment: See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/zZqQs/1/ not working.

Comment: @hab - it seems to be working for me... What exactly is not working? Do you not see the alert?

Comment: @Lix, it is not opening the link.

Comment: @hab - perhaps that is because you didn't actually open any link... See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/zZqQs/3/). Clicking on both the link and the div work for me (in chrome)

Comment: @Lix, great! Please update the answer with this code.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div style="background-color:orange">Click me to open the link
    <br>
    <a id="b" href="http://example.com">Link</a>
</div>

jQuery('div').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('b').click();
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zZqQs/4/

OR:

```
jQuery('a')[0].click();
```

Appears that jquery click and raw JS click differs from each other.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind using vanilla JavaScript if you are already in a jQuery function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<div style="background-color:orange">Click me to open the link
    <br>
    <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
</div>

<script>
    $('div').click(function () {
        $('a').click();
    });

    $('a').click(function (e) {

        alert('It came here!');
        e.stopPropagation();
        window.location = $("a").attr("href");
        return true;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I want to add 'target="_blank"' to the A-tag. will it work at that time?