# How to activate <a> event by clicking on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <div class="imgtumb"><img src="..."></div>
    <a href="toBigImg" class="imgtarget">sometext</a>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('div.imgtumb img').click(function() {
            $('a.imgtarget').click();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The link not work (dont open a big image). What i do wrong?

----Edited----
Thank you guys, but .trigger() is not working too. I resolved this problem something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('div.imgtumb img').click(function() {
            window.location.href = $('a.imgtarget').attr("href");
            });
        });
```

----Edited 2---
Question which explained why [.click() is not working with a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand)

Comment: and I found a topic which explained why .click() is not working with <a> tag - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand)

Comment: It's probably worth including that link here for others.

Comment: I meant include the URL to the topic :-) If you get 15 reputation you can turn your edit into [an answer to your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz).

Comment: o! got it and done :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.imgtumb img').click(function() {
        $('a.imgtarget').trigger('click');
        });
    });
</script>
```

the event trigger is the event to make another event to an element

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

use [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> . A call to .trigger() executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user:

try this

```
$('a.imgtarget').trigger('click');
```

instead of

```
 $('a.imgtarget').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this instead of .click()

```
window.open(
  'toBigImg',
  '_blank'
);
```