# JQuery 2.0.2: Trigger a click on a link

Tags: jquery, click

I recently upgraded from JQuery 1.7 to 2.0.2 and now I want to do a simple thing. If I stick with version 1.7 it works, but somehow it doesn't in version 2.0. :-/
I have two links on my page:

```
<span class="goButtons">
<a href="{$previousURL}" class="previousButton">&laquo;</a>
<a href="{$nextURL}" class="nextButton">&raquo;</a>
</span>
```

These two links refer to the previous and next image in my photo gallery. If I click on them they redirect me to the correct image. Now I wanted to add a keydown handler that triggers a click on these links if I press the left or right arrow key.

```
$(function () {
    $('.goButtons a').on('click', function () {
        console.log('a.' + $(this).prop('class') + ' was clicked... going to ' + $(this).prop('href'));
        return true;
    });

    $(window).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 37) 
            $('a.previousButton').trigger('click');
        else if (e.which == 39) 
            $('a.nextButton').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

If I open the page with Firebug active and press on the right arrow key, the console says:

> a.nextButton was clicked... going to /foto/11/

Unfortunately the browser doesn't start loading the linked page. It looks like as if it prevents it, but this is my only javascript on the page. :-(

Comment: This may help: http://www.techfoobar.com/2012/jquery-programmatically-clicking-a-link-and-forcing-the-default-action - *Disclaimer: Its my blog*

Comment: It worked, thank you, but I found another way to do this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do something like this and - surprise - it does work:

```
$('a.my_link')[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution. I changed it to

```
$('.goButtons a').on ('click', function () {
    window.location.href    =   $(this).prop ('href');
});
```

which works as intended. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a more detailed explanation why this doesn't work out of the box with `a.trigger('click')` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694803/2598398.