# Click on dynamically added link on KeyUp with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events, keyup

I use jQuery to add some HTML to the DOM. After the insertion I would like to create an eventhandler which is called on `keyup` and clicks on the link added to `el`. However, jQuery does not find the `a` element as it was added after loading the page.

```
var el = $("#name");
// add content to el
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    el.find('a').click();
});
```

How can I update the DOM in `el`? I know that there is `on()` (and its predecessors) in jQuery. However, they do not help me as the event is *not* registered on the added element itself, but on the document and another event just happens on the newly added element. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: How about binding the keyup event when you add the content ?

Comment: The `keyup` eventhandler apparently only fires in `input` and `textarea` elements.

Comment: Have you also tried binding it on window ?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear on this: It seems to only fire on input, textarea element *or* on document. But the firing of keyup was not the problem anyway.

Comment: You could maybe create a variable representing the element to be clicked (last added link in el), and emit a click event on that element on keyup while updating the reference (the value of that variable) everytime you add a new link. If i understand well.

Comment: Not sure whether you saw it or not, but the problem has already been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the response of @Johan I was doing further debugging and found the solution:

```
el.find('a')[0].click();
```

So the real problem was not the changing DOM but the `click()` event that apparently can only be applied to a single element and not to a list of only one element.

Some further discussion about `click()` not firing can be found here: [Can I call jquery click() to follow an <a> link if I haven't bound an event handler to it with bind or click already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand)

Comment: `click()` can be called on multiple elements.  Go to a regular page with jQuery and do $("a").click() and watch the fun begin! The problem is with dynamically added content.  I'm not sure why jQuery can't handle it (at least in the version I use which is like 1.7).