# Image not showing. Why triggered onclick behave differently than manual click on link?

Tags: php, jquery, onclick

My header has an image logo but it won't show if I have the triggered click to download a file:

```
 $("#test").click();
```

If I remove this script and try clicking on the text manually, the header image shows okay.
The link's:

```
<span id="test" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.example.com/download.php';"> . </span>
```

Why is this so? What's causing this problem?
Why does a triggered click behave differently than manual click on a link?

Is there something as a conflict on the image and jquery. Is that conflict even possible?

Comment: Can you provide us with some more code? You have tagged this as php but i can't see any php code?

Comment: sorry. I tagged this php coz maybe it has something to do with downloading a file on another php file . not really sure what's causing this problem

Comment: This > `. </span>`. **Q:** Are you trying to [**concatenate**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) something? I can't tell without seeing your full code.

Comment: No. That is just a period to be displayed.. It could be any text. But since the site's live and anyone could see a test text there, I just placed a period. that is the text i'm trying to click.

Comment: @SandaraKwon Ok, well without seeing your entire code, I or anyone else cannot be certain as to what may be causing the problem. **P.s.:** Please add the `@` symbol followed by my name, in order to address me personally, it helps. (wink) Cheers

Comment: @SandaraKwon Try using this `$("#test span").click();` see if that works then get back to me.

Comment: Are you sure you're callin $("#test").click() after the document has loaded?

Comment: @TrunalBhanse Yes, $("#test").click(); is working since it is downloading the file fine (meaning it was able to click on the link)

Comment: @Fred Tried $("#downloadNow span").click(); but it's not working.. Instead of downloading the file, nothing happens now as if the link has not been clicked.

Comment: Basically, the click is working fine just as I want it. The only problem is the logo image on the header. It's there since I can see it when I do inspect element on chrome but can't be seen on display. If I remove or comment out $("#test").click(); , the image will show and clicking on the link manually works. Is there something as a conflict on the image and jquery. Is that conflict even possible?

Comment: It's hard for me to say without seeing the actual full source and/or Web site @SandaraKwon

Comment: @Fred well, those two are the only important codes.. the rest are just html to design the page.. is there a way to load the image first before the triggered click is executed?

Comment: @SandaraKwon Again, I can't tell without seeing your entire source. I could pick at straws to say: Use `<img src="header.jpg border="0">` and delete the header image from inside your JS, yet I can guess "till the cows come home", and I stand at still being wrong. Until you show your full HTML and with the header image's name, I can no longer help you.

Comment: @Fred <div class="myheader">
     <div id="logo">
      <img src="logo.jpg" />
     </div>   
   </div>


<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#test").click();
 });
</script> 


<span id="test" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/freeEbookDL.php';"> . </span>

Comment: @SandaraKwon Is your JS `<script> $(document).ready(function() { $("#test").click(); }); </script>` inside `<head>` or `<body>`?

Comment: @SandaraKwon Try putting it inside `<head>` see if that will work and make your header image appear. Other than that, all I can think of is, if you haven't another nested `<div>` that they're both inside. Also, this could be a CSS issue. Check and see if you have a `hidden` statement inside CSS (`#myheader` and `#logo`). I take it you do have CSS happening. And check for `z-index` and `position`. Also, check to see the location of `logo.jpg` if the `src` is correct and not inside another folder. That's all I can think of for the moment.

Comment: @Fred It's not an issue with css or img src.. Like i said, if i remove the script to trigger click, the image is there.. The image is not visible only when i have that ONE LINE of code which is $("#test").click();

Comment: @SandaraKwon Sorry, at this point in time, I now need an actual visual. I can't wrap my head around it, sorry. Plus my brain has gone to mush. I hope you find what's wrong with it, as I can't help you with it, sorry Sandara I tried my best. Cheers *Peace*

Comment: @SandaraKwon You're welcome. Cheers *Peace*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this could fall under the category "fake clicking", which is not supported.
See [Can I call jquery click() to follow an <a> link if I haven't bound an event handler to it with bind or click already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand?rq=1)