# Trigger the click JS code on page load through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running following code on a link:-

```
$('#expertprofiles-category-filters .filterby > a').on("click", function () {
    // Figure out which category to show.
    var categoryId = $(this).attr('rel');

    // Hide the other subfilters.
    $("div.category-panel[rel!=" + categoryId + "]").slideUp(100);

    // Show the subfilters of the category.
    $("div.category-panel[rel=" + categoryId + "]").delay(100).slideDown(400);
});
```

This code runs fine but the problem is that I want to run this code on page load too, so that any one link is autaomatically selected.

### I tried this:-

```
$("#expertprofiles-category-filters .filterby").find('a').trigger('click');
```

But it doesn't work ...

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that `$('#expertprofiles-category-filters .filterby > a')` and `$("#expertprofiles-category-filters .filterby").find('a')` targets the same elements?

Comment: Yah, that's the intention.

Comment: Question which explained why .click() is not working with <a/> tag [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also do the following way,

```
$('#expertprofiles-category-filters .filterby > a').on("click", function () {
    // Figure out which category to show.
    var categoryId = $(this).attr('rel');

    // Hide the other subfilters.
    $("div.category-panel[rel!=" + categoryId + "]").slideUp(100);

    // Show the subfilters of the category.
    $("div.category-panel[rel=" + categoryId + "]").delay(100).slideDown(400);
}).trigger("click"); // triggers click on DOM ready
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same selector

```
$('#expertprofiles-category-filters .filterby > a').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $('#expertprofiles-category-filters .filterby > a').click();
```