# Simulating link click without interaction with user in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wanna simulate a click on href element, but without redirect the page on browser. Actually without the user's knowledge. How can I achieve this?

Example:

```
var books = new Array();
$('p.tree_item_leaf').each(function(){
    books.push($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
})
// for each book I wanna get the link and 'simulates' a click such that I can get the loaded content returned from the link in a variable
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $.map(books, function(book){book.trigger("click");})

Comment: Collect all the `href` values and perform an `XMLHttpRequest` for each value found. Since you use jQuery, you can just use `$.ajax` for that.

Comment: N.B.'s suggestion is correct. I didn't read the question carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Your remote click needs to be triggered somehow. In this example its being done by the `click-this` button

HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv" style="color: red;">Clicking this should open google even though this doesn't have an href</div>
<a class= "click-this" href="https://www.google.com">click this</a>
```

JS:

```
$(".myDiv").on("click mousedown mouseup focus blur keydown change", function(e) {
    $link = $(".click-this");
    console.log($link);

    $(".click-this")[0].click();
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0oecovtj/1/