# jQuery .trigger doesn't fire on enter keystroke

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, click

I'm trying to create an html & jQuery menu that uses arrow keys for navigation and the enter button to "click" the link in said menu.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4aqrm8z9/3/) and the menu is live on the [homepage of my website](http://digitalbrent.com) but here is the menu HTML:

```
<ul id="home_menu">
        <li class="arrow-link"><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/resume/">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="/portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tools">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And here is the `.arrow-link` class:

```
.arrow-link{
   background: url(media/images/selectArrow.png) no-repeat;
   background-position: 0 3px;
}
```

If you view the console you can see I'm recording two variables, the **Position Counter** which indicates the `<li>` element that the `.arrow-link` class gets applied to (see script below), and **Keystroke Value**, which is pretty self explanatory.

I have created a script that is pretty simple and that just toggles the `.arrow-link` class depending on the **Position Counter** value:

```
var pos = 1;

        jQuery(document).keydown(function (e) {

            switch (e.which) {

                case 38: // up

                    pos--;

                    if (pos > 5) {
                        pos = 1;
                    } else if (pos < 1) {
                        pos = 5;
                    }

                    moveArrow(pos, e.which);

                    break;

                case 40: // down

                    pos++;

                    if (pos > 5) {
                        pos = 1;
                    } else if (pos < 1) {
                        pos = 5;
                    }

                    moveArrow(pos, e.which);

                    break;

                case 13: // enter

                    console.log("Keystroke Value: " + e.which + " (Enter)");
                    jQuery('.arrow-link a').trigger("click");

                    break;


                default:
                    return; // exit this handler for other keys
            }
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
        });

        function moveArrow(pos, e) {

            console.log("Position counter: " + pos);
            console.log("Keystroke Value: " + e);
            jQuery("#home_menu").children().removeClass("arrow-link");
            jQuery("#home_menu li:nth-child(" + pos + ")").addClass("arrow-link");

        }
```

So from this script I know that the value being passed to the case statement is correct, and I can generate output to the console upon pressing the enter button, but, on the line where I try to simulate a click (`jQuery('.arrow-link a').trigger("click");`), nothing happens. I don't see any errors in the console, it just doesn't do anything.

I have also tried to use `(".arrow-link a").click();` instead of `jQuery('.arrow-link a').trigger("click");` but again, no dice.

What do I need to use there to take the user to the corresponding link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggering a click even on an 'a' element does not work in jQuery, however, you can simply use vanilla javascript:

```
document.querySelector('.arrow-link a').click();
```

You can see a working fiddle here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyn2y05h/)

This is similar to the issue here: [Can I call jquery click() to follow an <a> link if I haven't bound an event handler to it with bind or click already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand)

Comment: Oh yes, I had seen that question before but I couldn't find it the second time around for some reason. Thanks for posting it.