# How to trigger uper div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to trigger uper div element using jquery

```
<div class="abc">
<a href="abc.com" class="test"></a>
</div>

<div class="hit_uper_div">
     abc
</div>
```

Onclick of hit_uper_div i want to trigger a tag inside of abc div

```
jQuery('.hit_uper_div').click(function(event){
    console.log("hii");
    var a = jQuery('body').find('.abc a.test').text();
    console.log(a);
    jQuery('body').find('.abc a.test').trigger('click');
  });
```

Anyone have idea what exact wrong in this.

Comment: You don't need to use body just do `jQuery('.abc a.test')[0].trigger('click');`

Comment: I think your response is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquerys-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoking the click event (which does not perform the redirect) and navigating to the `href` position are two different things.

Your code only invokes the click method not redirect to your given URL. To navigate the given URL see the below example. In the example, if you don't want to open the URL in a new tab you can also use `window.location = $a.attr('href');`.

```js
jQuery('.hit_uper_div').click(function(event) {
  var $a = jQuery('body').find('.abc  a.test');
  window.open($a.attr('href'), '_blank');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">
  <a href="https://google.com/" class="test" target="_blank"></a>
</div>

<div class="hit_uper_div">
  abc
</div>
```

Snippet blocks my example to redirect a new URL, so here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Luyt1na6/) link.